# Argument of type '{ userInfo: string | null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am trying to create context-api to store userdetails and tokens in react using typescript, As I am new to typescript I cannot understand the following errors please help.
.................................................................................................

**Code:**

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

type Action =
  | { type: "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST"; }
  | { type: "USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS";payload: string}
  | { type: "USER_LOGIN_FAIL"; payload: string };

interface UserAuthProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
type AppState = typeof INITIAL_STATE;

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  userInfo: localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
    ? localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
    : null,
};

const userLoginreducer = (state: AppState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST":
      return { loading: true };
    case "USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return { loading: false, success: true, userInfo: action.payload };
    case "USER_LOGIN_FAIL":
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state
   }
};

 const UserAuthContext = createContext<{
   state: AppState;
   dispatch: React.Dispatch<Action>;
 }>(INITIAL_STATE);

 function UserAuthProvider({ children }: UserAuthProviderProps) {
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userLoginreducer, INITIAL_STATE);

   return (
     <UserAuthContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
       {children}
     </UserAuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { UserAuthContext, UserAuthProvider };
```

**Errors**

```
  Type '{ userInfo: string | null; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ state: 
  { userInfo: string | null; }; dispatch: Dispatch<Action>; }': state, dispatch

   Argument of type '{ userInfo: string | null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 
   'never'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You context should have type `AppState`:

```
type AppState = {
  userInfo: string | null,
  success: boolean,
  error: string,
};

const INITIAL_STATE: AppState = {
  userInfo: localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
    ? localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
    : null,
  success: true,
  error: '',
};

const UserAuthContext = createContext<AppState>(INITIAL_STATE);
```